# Allowing TypeScript to infer type from a factory

Tags: typescript, types, inference

Is it possible for TypeScript to infer the return type from a static function. For example if I have a static `User.fromId()` function it will return a `User` object. But I want to pass it through another function (call it `builder`) - e.g:

```
builder(User.fromId, values);
```

where `builder` is defined as:

```
function builder( construct: Function, values: any ) {
   var inst = construct();
   // set values
   return inst;
}
```

How can I get TypeScript to "know" that `builder` is going to return a `User` without passing `User` as a generic? Perhaps it can, but using `Function` as the type for the first parameter is the issue? If so, can the inference be done without a generic, which I know I could use to define the return type (but it feels redundant).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use generic type parameters and the appropriate function signature, Typescript will infer the types correctly

```
class User {
    static fromId(id: number): User{
        return new User()
    }
}

function builder<T>(construct: (id:number) => T, values: any) {
var inst = construct(values);
// set values
return inst;
}

let u = builder(User.fromId, 0); //User
```

We can even infer the parameter type if necessary

```
function builder<T, TId>(construct: (id:TId) => T, values: TId) {
    var inst = construct(values);
    // set values
    return inst;
}

let u = builder(User.fromId, 0);
let u2 = builder(User.fromId, '0'); // error
```

If the constructor function has more parameters we can even infer those if needed, using tuples in rest parameters

```
class User {
    static fromId(id: number, name: string): User{
        return new User()
    }
}

function builder<T, TArgs extends any[]>(construct: (...a:TArgs) => T, ...values: TArgs) {
    var inst = construct(...values);
    // set values
    return inst;
}

let u = builder(User.fromId, 0, '');
let u2 = builder(User.fromId, '0'); // error
```